# Why the Equality Axioms are considered as logical axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , page 94-95 , **First order theories with equality**.There is a line which is kind of confusing for me.

> The numbering (A6) and (A7) is a continuation of the numbering of the logical axioms.

Here , (A6) and (A7) are the following axioms:

$(A6)$ $(\forall x_1)x_1=x_1$ 
$(A7)$ $x=y \to (\mathscr B(x,x) \to \mathscr B(x,y))$

My question is , why they are considered logical axioms ? Shouldn't they be in the category of proper (or non-logical) axioms?

Comment: [Your choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).  Do you want first order logic with equality or first order logic without equality?  The former is more usual

Comment: @Henry Lets say I wanted First order theories with equality , then shouldn't (A6) and (A7) be proper axioms because they are not logically valid?

Comment: @Prithubiswas In first-order logic without equality, $=$ isn't even a privileged symbol, so yes if you wanted to include them they would be proper axioms. (Technically the second one is a schema.)

Comment: @JamesHanson Oh ok , so they would be proper axioms. And you are right , = is not a privileged symbol. Also , I know that the second one is a axiom schema.

Comment: A6 and A7 are logical axioms if and only if equality is a logical concept. That is (as @Henry said) if your *logic* contains equality, then these axioms are logical. If your logic doesn't contain equality but some *theory* does, then these are proper axioms of that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your criterion of what counts as a "logical constant"? The connectives and first-order quantifiers count as logical notions -- but why?

There are various stories on the market for demarcating the logical constants.  Depending on the details, some count the identity predicate as a logical constant, some don't. For an accessible discussion of some of the options here, see e.g. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-constants/

But certainly, some standard accounts do treat the notion of identity as logical: it is topic neutral and general enough; it is governed by introduction and elimination rules in the right sort of way, and so on. Mendelson is not at all going out on a limb in treating the identity laws as logical.